# How to delete columns in certain worksheets and other columns in other worksheets? Vba Excel

Tags: vba, excel

i want to go to certain worksheets and delete the same columns. But i also have another group of worksheets where I want to delete other columns. Here is the code I have so far. It doesnt work!

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long

  For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
  Select Case wks.Name
  Case "AT", "RA", "AO", "FO SG 380 PLT_CMA", "8K", "C3 CONW INW OPIS_CMA", "A5", "DIESEL OHR EIA_CMA", "BO", "DIESEL OHR EIA_CWA", "C3 MBEL TET OPIS_CMA", "GO ICE_CMA", "ULA2"
      Sheets(i).Range("S:AE").ClearContents
      Sheets(i).Range("O:O").ClearContents
      Sheets(i).Range("M:M").Clear Contents
      Sheets(i).Range("L:L").ClearContents
      Sheets(i).Range("G:H").ClearContents
  Case Else
      Sheets(i).Columns("S:AE").Delete
      Sheets(i).Columns("O:O").Delete
      Sheets(i).Columns("K:K").Delete
      Sheets(i).Columns("G:H").Delete
  End Select

Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Should wks.Name be Sheets(i).Name ?

Comment: Have you set wks to a worksheet? It looks like you could do `For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` instead of using For i

Comment: Or what @QHarr asked. Beating me to the punch... :)

Comment: @QHarr That was the problem! Didnt spot it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
Select Case Worksheets(i).Name
```

To ensure testing actual sheet names looping over.

I would also loop over the worksheets collection to avoid dealing with chart sheets (hence my use of Worksheet above)

So loop would be to `Worksheets.Count`

There is a typo  for one ClearContents and decide if deleting or clearing.